# How to zoom to layer which is invisible at load time?

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I have a layer whose maxResolution is set when it is added to the map, so that it will only be visible at a certain zoom level.

When the user clicks on a button called **zoomto layer**, I want to zoom to that particular layer. But when I try to take the extent of that layer, it's always getting *infinity* as it's not visible in the map.

My code:

```
let lay = this.mapService.getLayerByName(layer.layerName);
    let resolution = lay.getMaxResolution();
    let map = this.mapService.getMap();
    let zoom = Math.floor(map.getView().getZoomForResolution(resolution)+1);
    map.getView().setZoom(zoom);

    let layerExtent = lay.getSource().getExtent();
    console.log("layerExtent",layerExtent)

    this.mapService.fitExtent(layerExtent);
    map.getView().fit(lay.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
    map.getView().setZoom(zoom);
```

Is there any way to zoom to a layer which is not visible at that moment?

Answer (score 2):

The GetCapabilities response of your WFS contains the bounding box (along with the projection) of your layer. You can parse it and zoom to the BBox.

You can take a look at the [GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getcapabilities)  docs. As WFS is a standard protocol, other map servers offer the same features.